# JQueryUI - Dialog over dialog not working in Chrome/IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am relatively new to JQuery and struggling with the following scenario in Chrome/IE. **It works perfectly in FF**.
I have an import dialog where we import certain number of records. So while import is in progress I want to show a progress bar so I am trying to render another modal dialog with progress bar. Chrome/IE won't render the waitdialog.

Here is the source code:

```
$("#itemimportviewdlg").dialog({
        width: 600,
    height: 650,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    title: "Import Data",
    closeOnEscape: false, //dont allow esc to close dlg
    buttons: {
        "Import": function() {          
            $("#waitdialog").dialog({
                width: 350,
                height: 150,
                modal: true,
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                title: "Progress...",
                stack: true,
                closeOnEscape: false, //dont allow esc to close dlg
            });

            $( "#waitdialog" ).dialog( "moveToTop" );

            var weight = importItemsTbl.fnGetNodes().length / 100;
            $("#importprogress").attr("aria-valuemax", $("input:checked", importItemsTbl.fnGetNodes()).length);

            $("input:checked", importItemsTbl.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
                          // import functionality
                          var progCnt = (itemAddedCnt/weight>>0);
                          $('#importprogress').css('width', progCnt+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', progCnt);                                                    
                          $("#importprogress").text(progCnt+'%');
                        });
                   });

        $("#waitdialog").dialog("destroy");
```

Comment: So what is the issue? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I just edited the post. Chrome/IE don't render the progress dialog. I tried using "stack" property but JQueryUI documentation says its been removed from 1.10

Comment: Which jQuery and jQuery UI versions are you using?

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.10.4 and jQuery - v1.7.2

Comment: I finally got it working. There was no issue in the code, I just had to clear the browser cache. I wonder how it worked in FF though :)